# Displaying canvas in the same line

Tags: html, css

What i am trying to do here is to display several canvas in the same line. I have try display inline but it's not working. It's still display one per line.

```
<div>
   <p>Camera</p>
   <canvas class='camera' width='50' height='50'>
</div>

<div>
   <p>Multimedia</p>
   <canvas class='multimedia' width='50' height='50'>
</div>
```

This is what i have include in the style tag

```
<style>
    .canvas{
       display:inline-block;}
</style>
```

Comment: `<div>` is a block element. Shouldn't it put them on different lines?

Comment: Give `canvas` class to div and check! [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/y8ZTj/)

Comment: @Max which is why OP is asking how to put them on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the period in front of the CSS selector.

Should read `canvas {` not `.canvas {`

The latter select a class, whereas the former selects the actual tag.

Also, give the `<div>` and `<p>` tags a style of `inline` or `inline-block` as well. By default they are block elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

### [*Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/4eGQS/)